# What is error 2203 when trying to install Windows Office Home and Student 2010?

Tags: windows-7, installation, microsoft-office

I am running Office Home and Student 2007 on Windows 7 Professional. I purchased and want to install Office Home and Student 2010. I get the error 2203 when trying to install. What is this error and how do I correct?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Support has a solution page for you: [Link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2000547)

Cause: The default user temporary folder (%temp%) has insufficient permissions assigned to it.

If this resolution does not work for you, take a look at [this thread](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/officeinstall/thread/b11b5e8f-c05c-45c0-8d57-a3fa430fd36f) on Microsoft Social Answers which exactly covers the same issue.